# Toggle .wp-caption-text only for image it belongs to

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, mouseover, caption

I experienced a problem while trying to build a jquery-snippet to show the caption of an image on mouseover in wordpress. Everytime I hover over one of the images the captions of all images are loaded one by one and then only the one of the last picture is showing up.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wp-caption').mouseover(function(){

        $('.wp-caption').children('.wp-caption-text').show(0);
      }).mouseout(function(){
        $('.wp-caption').children('.wp-caption-text').hide(0);
    });
});
```

I need a way to just show the caption specified to the image it belongs to.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `$('.wp-caption')` simply use `$(this)`. To only affect the element on which the mouseover and mouseout occured.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wp-caption').mouseover(function(){
          $(this).children('.wp-caption-text').show()
      }).mouseout(function(){
          $(this).children('.wp-caption-text').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: It couldn't be easier! Thanks for your help!